# Dynamics CRM Winforms Integration - .NET Framework Backward Compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I developed a windows forms application which pulls data from Dynamics CRM online & displays that retrieved data in my application. My application uses .NET Framework 4.5.2.

I have an existing application which was built on .NET Framework 4.5. Now, I want to use the code from my new forms application(f/w - 4.5.2) into this existing application (f/w - 4.5).

When I tried to integrate, the XRM packages thrown an error that they support only for f/w - 4.5.2

I looked in the internet if there is any chance to over come these errors but I failed to find any solution.

I think there is no solution to do, as per [this MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/02/01/dynamics-365-sdk-backwards-compatibility/) & I have no hope.

*Note:In MSDN, they didn't give any info for 4.5*

One more thing to add is I was using XRM 8.x in 4.5.2 & now I'm downgrading these versions to 7.x to support 4.5 framework. but the API is different between 8.x & 7.x

I'm posting this though, if anyone could shred some light to resolve my problem!!!

Comment: As you observed, If your CRM is 2015+ then you have to use 4.5.2 or higher in order to be able to use the SDK assemblies. I agree with @Jordi to just change your old projects .net Version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, it would be a lot easier to just upgrade the existing application to use .NET 4.5.2. There shouldn't be any major breaking changes between 4.5 and 4.5.2, so the code you had in 4.5 should just work fine in 4.5.2.

Comment: Thanks Jordi, but I'm looking for a better solution if there is any. Or else I should be using the CRM SDK 2015 only :( as existing project is huge & don't want to cause new problems by changing the frmaework to 4.5.2 though the chance of breaking is a very very less.